# It does not work 'await' when I convert an Observable into Promise to be able to do it asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, async-await

I need to use 'await' to wait for the services to return the data.

The method of service (PartidoProvider) is:

```
buscarPartido ( jugador1: Jugador, jugador2: Jugador ) :Observable<Partido[]> {
  let partidoGanaJugador1: Partido = new Partido();
  let partidoPierdeJugador1: Partido = new Partido();

  partidoGanaJugador1.jugadorGanador = jugador1.idDoc;
  partidoGanaJugador1.jugadorPerdedor = jugador2.idDoc;

  partidoPierdeJugador1.jugadorGanador = jugador2.idDoc;
  partidoPierdeJugador1.jugadorPerdedor = jugador1.idDoc;

  return Observable.zip(  this.get(partidoGanaJugador1), 
                        this.get(partidoPierdeJugador1), 
                        (listaGanados, listaPerdidos) => {                                  
                              return listaGanados.concat(listaPerdidos);
});
```

When the data is checked, it is necessary to wait for the data returned by the previous service. In the following code fragment I put the example with which I am working:

```
  async enviarResultado(){
    let rival: Jugador;
    let jugador: Jugador = this.authProvider.jugador;
    let nombreRival: string;
    let partido: Partido;


    // Obtener partido del calendario para añadirle el resultado    
    nombreRival = this.myForm.controls['rival'].value;        
    rival = this.rivales.find( rival => rival.nombre == nombreRival);    

    // This works and return data
    this.partidoProvider.buscarPartido(jugador, rival).subscribe(
        resultado => {
          console.log("El subscribe ha devuelto datos");
          console.log(resultado);          
        },
        error => {
          console.error("Se ha producido un error al intentar buscar el partido para modificar el resultado")
        }
    );  

    // this never returns data
    console.log("1");                
    await this.partidoProvider.buscarPartido(jugador,rival).toPromise()
          .then( lista => {
            console.log("2");
            console.log("Promesa entra");
            console.log("data:" + lista);                      
            if ( lista && lista.length > 0){
              partido = lista[0]
            }
          })
          .catch( error => {
            console.log("2");
            console.error("Se ha producido un error al intentar buscar el partido para modificar el resultado")
        });
  console.log("3");
  console.log("Partido encontrado:" + partido);
}
```

When it is executed and the service is invoked with the "subscribe" it works correctly, but it is not what I need.

When I invoke it with the await and use the method "toPromise ()" does not return any data, only the result of "console.log (" 1 ") appears in the debug console.

Content of the debug console:

```
1
result-detail.ts:125 El subscribe ha devuelto datos
result-detail.ts:126
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Remove the `then` and bear in mind that with `await` it will now return `lista`, so you'll need to do something like `let lista = await this.partidoProvider.buscarPartido(jugador,rival).toPromise()`

Answer (score 0):

You mixed [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with [Async Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

You can either:

```
this.partidoProvider.buscarPartido(jugador,rival).toPromise()
      .then( lista => {
        console.log("2");
        console.log("Promesa entra");
        console.log("data:" + lista);                      
        if ( lista && lista.length > 0){
          partido = lista[0]
        }
      })
      .catch( error => {
        console.log("2");
        console.error("Se ha producido un error al intentar buscar el partido para modificar el resultado")
    });
```

Or

```
try {
   const lista = await this.partidoProvider.buscarPartido(jugador,rival).toPromise()
   console.log("2");
   console.log("Promesa entra");
   console.log("data:" + lista);                      
   if ( lista && lista.length > 0){
      partido = lista[0]
    }
 } catch( error) {
     console.log("2");
     console.error("Se ha producido un error al intentar buscar el partido para modificar el resultado")
 }
```

`await` returns the promise into a new variable, that why `const lista = await...`.

Because `await` doesn't have `then/catch` we need to `try/catch` the response.

so this is the 'layout':

```
async fn() {
   try {
      const respone = await <AsyncCall>;
      ...
      ...
   } catch (error) {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: Hi Itamar, thanks for the reply. I tried to do what you say but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

the problem will not be anything related to the await.

The problem was that in the service does not complete the observable and to turn it into a promise never finished.

The solution was to add .take (1) to the service, as follows:

```
 buscarPartido ( jugador1: Jugador, jugador2: Jugador ) : Observable<Partido[]> {
    let partidoGanaJugador1: Partido = new Partido();
    let partidoPierdeJugador1: Partido = new Partido();

    partidoGanaJugador1.jugadorGanador = jugador1.idDoc;
    partidoGanaJugador1.jugadorPerdedor = jugador2.idDoc;

    partidoPierdeJugador1.jugadorGanador = jugador2.idDoc;
    partidoPierdeJugador1.jugadorPerdedor = jugador1.idDoc;

    return Observable.zip(  this.get(partidoGanaJugador1), 
                        this.get(partidoPierdeJugador1), 
                        (listaGanados, listaPerdidos) => {                                  
                              return listaGanados.concat(listaPerdidos);
     }).take(1);
  }
```

Thanks for the help.

Greetings.